# QThread finished() signal is never emited

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

so i have a worker class that has 2 slots: StartWork() and StopWork(), the StartWork() one runs an infinite loop (it just reads and reads camera input non-stop) and the StopWork() method just sets a bool variable to false (so the loop inside StartWork() stops).

according to the QThread documentation, the best way to use them now is not by sub-classing but by moving workers into the thread, so that's what i do. problem is, the started() signal from the thread gets called but the finished() signal never gets called.

worker class slots:

> void StartWork(){ running = true; while(running){ do work; }}
>
> void StopWork(){ running = false; }

QThread initialization and signal/slot connection:

```
thread = new QThread();
worker = new Worker();
worker.moveToThread(thread);

QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(StartWork()));
QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(StopWork()));
```

and on my QPushButton i do this:

```
if(pushStartStop->text().toLower() == "start")
{
    pushStartStop->setText("Stop");
    thread->start();
}
else
{
    pushStartStop->setText("Start");
    thread->quit();
}
```

the thread->start() works fine, and the StartWork() gets called and everything is beautiful (GUI runs with no blocks, etc).

but thread->quit() doesn't do anything, it gets called (because the button changes text) but thats it. if i just call worker->StopWork() it works, but then i can't start it again.

I've tried with thread->exit(); but the results are the same. Also i know sub-classing works, but it looks uglier and according to the recent Qt documentation, sub-classing is no longer optimal.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a forever loop:

```
void StartWork()
{
    running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        do work;
    }
}
```

This function will loop, so the event loop of the thread is blocked just after having emitted `started()`. Thus, `finished()` cannot be emitted.

**Solution 1:**

Add the function

```
void DoWork()
{
    if(running)
    {
        do work
    }
}
```

To Worker, and change

```
void StartWork()
{
    running = true;
}
```

Then, just connect `DoWork` to a timer in the thread.

**Solution 2:**

Change the function

```
void StartWork()
{
    running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        do work;
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

With this solution, you will have to restart the thread when the worker stops its job (`StopWork()` will force this function to finish, so the event loop will have no events to handle and the thread will be finished).

Comment: You probably forgot to remove `while(running)` in `doWork`.

Comment: hello and thanks so much for the answer. i took some time to reply because i was reading the timer documentation. I'm having a bit of trouble to understand where to place the timer. i tried placing it inside the worker class but Qt gave me 2 errors: "cant start timers from another thread" and "cant stop timers from another thread" so i guess the timer has to be outside the worker class? tried that using a "if(running)" instead of "while" since that StartWork() and StopWork() just toggle the running boolean now, but it didnt work. can you explain better where to place the QTimer please? thanks.

Comment: @Lol Fixed, thanks. For sap: You have to start the timer after having moved the worker to the thread

Comment: Hi Synxis, all. Sorry for the noob question but why put a timer in? and where? Thanks

Comment: @smurff The timer is to simulate a continuous operation by calling its main part at regular intervals of time. Don't forget to see my edit.