# QThread::finished() is never emitted?

Tags: multithreading, qt4

I don't have a forever loop [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942461/qthread-finished-signal-is-never-emited?rq=1), but it still doesn't emit the finished() signal,

In the constructor of a class:

```
connect (&thread, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(threadFunc()));
connect (&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(finished()));
```

In the finished() function,

```
void XX::finished()
{
  qDebug() << "Completed";
}

void XX::threadFunc()
{
  qDebug() << "Thread finished"; // only single line, finishes immediately
}
```

But I never see the `finished()` get called, everytime before I start the thread with `thread.start()`, I must call `thread.terminate()` manually, did I misunderstood the usage of QThread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QThread` will emit `finished` signal when `QThread::run` method is finished. Perhaps, you have incorrect implementation of this.

Default implementation of `run` method looks like this. It just calls another `exec` method.

```
void QThread::run()
{
    (void) exec();
}
```

Implementation of `exec` method is a bit more complex. Now I simplified it.

```
int QThread::exec()
{
    // .....

    if (d->exited) {
        return d->returnCode;   
    }

    // ......

    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    int returnCode = eventLoop.exec();
    return returnCode;
}
```

Judging by code, it can finish in two cases. In first case if it is already exited. In second it enters the event loop and waits until `exit()` is called.

How we can see now, your infinity thread loop is here. So you need `QThread::quit()` which is equal `QThread::exit(0)`.

**P.S.** Don't use `terminate`. It is dangerous.

Comment: @warl0ck so It means your thread has default implementation and waits `exit`, as I said above.